# Azure devops VSBuild , Argument Outputpath

Tags: asp.net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Hello I need to upload to Artifact the results of the VSBuild of the Solution but I can not use OutPutpath I get an error that the solution can not copy to certain files.
If I do not put an outputpath in the argument everything works fine, but I do not know what is the place of the VSBuild results to upload them to Artifact.

Answer (score 0):

When using the **VSBuild task** to build a solution, normally the build artifact should be output into the directory of each project in the solution. So, the output path you set on the **VSBuild task** should be a relative path to each project directory.

You can follow the steps below to set up your pipeline:

1. On the **VSBuild task**, set the output path like as this.

   ```
   -p:OutputPath={the relative path}
   ```

   [image]
2. After the build, use the **Copy files** task to copy the artifact files form the output path to the directory **`$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`**.

   [image]
3. Then use the **Publish Pipeline Artifacts task** to publish the artifact files from the directory **`$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`**.

   [image]

The above are the most common steps to build projects and publish build artifacts in the build pipelines.